# How to use infinite loop in jasmine framework(protractor)?

Tags: protractor

I am new to protractor, In my script I want to automate `it` block(jasmine framework) continuously for a day. When I use infinite loop I am getting error: `heap out of memory javascript`.

Below is my code:

```
it('test case one', function(){   
    while(true){    
        browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handle) {
            var firstWindow = handle[0];
            browser.switchTo().window(firstWindow).then(function () { 
                browser.refresh();
                browser.sleep(8000);
                browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,550);').then(function () { 
                    browser.sleep(8000);
                });
            }); 
         });
        browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handle) {
            var secondWindow = handle[1];
            browser.switchTo().window(secondWindow).then(function () { 
            browser.sleep(8000);
            element(by.linkText('1')).click();
            browser.sleep(6000);
            element(by.linkText('2')).click();
            browser.sleep(5000);
            element(by.linkText('3')).click();
            browser.sleep(5000);
           });  
         });        
        }
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Hai Sudharsan, thank you for your response. I got the solution 
 used setInterval(function(){}, 200)